# How to delete a file in USER PROFILE using swift code

Tags: swift, try-catch

This is the code that works very well but need to enter the correct path as user profile : `UserName`

```
let filePathString = "file:///Users/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts"
guard let fileUrl = URL(string: "\(filePathString)") else { return }

do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
    print("Remove successfully")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("An error took place: \(error)")
}
```

How to set UserName as a variable?
Thanks, everybody!

Comment: Apps are sandboxed. You can't get into the `.ssh/known_hosts` file. But in any case you don't need to know the user name; just start at the home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `let homeDirURL = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser`

This will only work if you're working on macOS, with the sandbox turned off.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
let fullpath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let result = fullpath.absoluteString.split(separator: "/").suffix(2)
if let name = result.first {
    let filePathString = "file:///Users/" + String(name) + "/.ssh/known_hosts"
    print("\n" + filePathString + "\n")
 }
```